# Better install Ubuntu 14.04 before upgrade to Windows 10 or afterwards?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, windows-10

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 and would like to install Ubuntu's latest LTS in dual boot with Windows.

Is it better to upgrade to Windows 10 first and then install Ubuntu or is it better to install Ubuntu now in dual boot and later upgrade Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to upgrade Windows first, as it will probably check and overwrite the bootloader with its own.

Installing Ubuntu will also replace the bootloader, but with GRUB which usually detects all installed systems and allows you to boot each of them. The Windows bootloader however assumes it's the only OS and does not care about anything else.

Therefore if you install Ubuntu as last step, you will automatically have a (probably working) GRUB bootloader in the end which detects and shows both Windows and Ubuntu.
If you upgrade Windows last, you will have the Windows bootloader which doesn't show Ubuntu and you would have to install GRUB again.

Comment: If it's UEFI, the booloader in the ESP will not be overwritten. What could happen tough, is that the order of boot entry are changed and defaults to windows being the first, preventing grub to be run at boot.  I have upgraded to Windows 10 here.  Nothing bad happened for Ubuntu

Comment: If system is/was Windows 8 and pre-installed then UEFI. Windows will not overwrite the Ubuntu entry, but will change UEFI boot order so it is first. And many systems need work arounds to boot and you have to be sure to turn off fast startup in Windows and fast boot in UEFI. Shows Windows 8, but Windows 10 should be similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am only used to BIOS installations (never touched or wanted to touch a Windows newer than 7), so I did not know that.

Comment: Hi all, at the end I have updated to windows 10 first, and then I installed ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with windows. Just to inform you, I had no problem rebooting the pc, that worked perfecly with grub 2. Thank you all for you kind answers.

Comment: @G.Calvarese As you say that this answer helped you and solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the grey tick symbol on the left of it. Also make sure you have read our little [tour] page to learn the basics about how this site works in only two minutes. :-) Thanks!